# Sending data from HTML form to a Python script in Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, input, flask

I have the code below in my Python script:

```
def cmd_wui(argv, path_to_tx):
    """Run a web UI."""
    from flask import Flask, flash, jsonify, render_template, request
    import webbrowser
    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/tx/index/')
    def index():
        """Load start page where you select your project folder
        or load history projects from local DB."""
        from txclib import get_version
        txc_version = get_version()
        prj = project.Project(path_to_tx)

        # Let's create a resource list from our config file
        res_list = []
        prev_proj = ''
        for idx, res in enumerate(prj.get_resource_list()):
                hostname = prj.get_resource_host(res)
        username, password = prj.getset_host_credentials(hostname)
        return render_template('init.html', txc_version=txc_version, username=username)
```

Also, I have an HTML form in init.html:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="projectFilepath" size="40" placeholder="Spot your project files">
<input type="button" id="spotButton" value="Spot">
</form>
```

How can I pass the user input from "projectFilepath" when a user clicks "spotButton" on a variable in my python script?

I'm new in Python and Flask, so forgive me if I make any mistakes.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The `form` tag needs some attributes set:

1. `action`: The URL that the form data is sent to on submit. Generate it with `url_for`. It can be omitted if the same URL handles showing the form and processing the data.
2. `method="post"`: Submits the data as form data with the POST method. If not given, or explicitly set to `get`, the data is submitted in the query string (`request.args`) with the GET method instead.
3. `enctype="multipart/form-data"`: When the form contains file inputs, it must have this encoding set, otherwise the files will not be uploaded and Flask won't see them.

The `input` tag needs a `name` parameter.

Add a view to handle the submitted data, which is in `request.form` under the same key as the input's `name`. Any file inputs will be in `request.files`.

```
@app.route('/handle_data', methods=['POST'])
def handle_data():
    projectpath = request.form['projectFilepath']
    # your code
    # return a response
```

Set the form's `action` to that view's URL using `url_for`:

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('handle_data') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="projectFilepath">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 75):

You need a Flask view that will receive *POST* data and an HTML `form` that will send it.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/addRegion', methods=['POST'])
def addRegion():
    ...
    return (request.form['projectFilePath'])
```

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('addRegion') }}" method="post">
    Project file path: <input type="text" name="projectFilePath"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```