# How to html input to Flask?

Tags: python, html, http, web, flask

I have this html bit:

```
<form action='quiz_answers'>
    <p> Question1? </p>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2">Answer1</input>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1">Answer2</input>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">Answer3</input>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="0">Answer4</input>

    <p> Question2? </p>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2">Answer1</input>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1">Answer2</input>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">Answer3</input>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">Answer4</input>
</form>
```

and this python code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

@app.route('/quiz')
def quiz():
    return render_template('quiz.html')

@app.route('/quiz_answers', methods=['POST'])
def quiz_answers():
    q1 = request.form['q1']
    q2 = request.form['q2']
    q4 = request.form['q4']
    q5 = request.form['q5']

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

How would I go about adding making a button which, after it has been clicked on + question 1 and 2 have been answered, opens a new template with the results? So in short, how do I make a button saying "Yup, the questions have been answered, count the values and return them in a new HTML page"?

The Flask Quick Start tutorial does go trough HTTP requests but doesn't answer my quetion in this specific situation. Googling only yielded [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556958/sending-data-from-html-form-to-python-flask) which didn't bring me anywhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to add a `submit` button to the form to POST or GET the data response back to the `action`.

In this case, you will probably want to modify your form tag definition to:

```
<form action="/quiz_answers" method="POST">
```

And add a submit button like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
```

When the user clicks, it should generate a POST request back to `http://your_server/quiz_answers`.

Comment: Yup that worked flawlessly. Marked your answer as accepted answer. :]