# Python Flask Web Application - Multi-line Input Option

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, flask

I am building a Flask application that has a text box and allows users to type in a domain name and submit the form with a button (the results of the search appear in HTML below the search box). I want to support multiple domain entry at once using a **textarea** input box. How can I use a button to toggle the form (or use a separate form) between using the text box input and the text area based on the button the user selects? And how can I take the input from the related box and process it in python?

Comment: Instead of toggling between the two, it might be easier to use the TextArea element and count how many domains are inside. Also, this question may be a partial duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556958/sending-data-from-html-form-to-a-python-script-in-flask

Answer (score 1):

You can rely on a single line of input and use `jquery` to keep adding new domains as needed:

`app.py`:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
  return flask.render_template('get_domains.html')

@app.route('/add_domain')
def add_domain():
  _domains = flask.request.args.getlist('domains[]') 
  return flask.jsonify({"success":"true"})
  #do something with domains
```

In `get_domains.html`, use `jquery` to get all entries and `ajax` to communicate with the `/add_domain` route:

```
<html>
 <header>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </header>
 <body>
   <div class='outer'> <!--Used to anchor jquery updates -->
     <div class='input_section'></div>
     <button class='add_domain'>Add domain</button>
   </div>
 </body>
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   var count = 1;
   var button_count = 0;
   $('.outer').on('click', '.add_domain', function(){
    var new_html = `
    <input type='text' name='domain' id='domain${count}'>
    <div class='spacer' style='height:10px;'></div>
    `
    $('.input_section').append(new_html);
     count += 1;
     if(button_count == 0){
       $('.outer').append('<button class="submit_data" id="submit_stuff">Add all</button>')
       button_count += 1;
     }
    });
     $('.outer').on('click', '.submit_data', function(){
      var results = [];
      for (var i = 1; i < count; i++){
       results.push($('#domain'+i.toString()).val());
      }
      $('.input_section').html('');
      $('#submit_stuff').remove();
      count = 1;
      button_count = 0;
      $.ajax({
      url: "/add_domain",
      type: "get",
      data: {domains: results},
       success: function(response) {
       //pass
      },
       error: function(xhr) {
      //pass
     }
   });
    });
  });
 </script>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]