# Getting Flask Request Data

Tags: python, flask

Bit of a noob with Flask, sorry.

My application is collecting the value from a drop down then POSTing that string to my flask function. I can (sort of) get at the data by using:

```
@app.route("/lookupmember", methods=["POST"])
def lookupmember():
    member = request.data
    print(member)
    return member
```

Interestingly though when I print the value of "member" out there in the python function I see something like:

`127.0.0.1 - - [19/Oct/2018 18:15:31] "POST /lookupmember HTTP/1.1" 200 -
b'john doe'`

Whats the `b'` before the name `'john doe'`?

When I console.log the same value after passing it back in the Ajax caller only the name is printed in the browser console.

I reckon the b' part might be a key or identifier applied by flask? If so, it seems reasonable that there would be a way to use that to parse to get to just the name?

Comment: the b is because it's a python `bytes` literal - i'm not sure why it's being printed that way on your console. What command are you running to run the http server?

Comment: Just running it from PyCharm:

Its going to make processing the code a bit inelegant if I need to strip off the b' every time. Wonder how I could just get at the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending data from HTML form to a Python script in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556958/sending-data-from-html-form-to-a-python-script-in-flask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `member` is of type `bytes`, then you should convert it to a string using the `decode()` function. Then convert that result to JSON so that you can read it in your browser using the `jsonify` function:

```
@app.route("/lookupmember", methods=["POST"])
def lookupmember():
    member = request.data
    print(member)
    return jsonify(member.decode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: I just get:
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Comment: Gotcha, then you have to convert the bytes to a string. I have updated my answer.

Comment: you can also use `request.get_json()`, see  [doc](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json)

Comment: Can you advice about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63698809/flasks-request-data-returns-bytes-data-however-sometimes-automatically-decoded