# Flask's request.data returns bytes data, however sometimes automatically decoded

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am using Postman to invoke a flask POST endpoint with an .xml file

For most of the .xml files the Flask's `request.data` returns bytes data (encoded). Example:

```
b'\xff\xfe\x001\x006........\r\x001\n\x00'
```

However, for couple of the files the value in the request.data is bytes but the contents looks to be automatically decoded. Example:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbfsome human readable value here.....text\r\n'
```

What exactly is the cause of this behavior? I cannot see any striking difference between the xml files that give the above outputs.

Comment: some bytes are codes of printable chars and simply it prints them as chars instead codes. but it is still bytes data - they are not decoded to string. It only print them on screen as chars to make it more readable for human

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second example is still byte code. It is not decoded, it just happens that certain byte values can be represented as ASCII chars.

So, nothing to worry.