# How to call python function on button press in flask without javascript?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to flask framework, what I want to do is very simple but I cant seem to find a solution online which does not use javascript (I dont know any javascript, which is why I want to avoid it for now).

I want to call python function when user presses a button.

Here is HTML button:

```
<input type="submit" name="A" value="submit_A">
```

Python code:

```
@app.route('/submit_a', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit_a():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # code to detect button press
        # do stuff
    return redirect(url_for('upload_page'))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556958/sending-data-from-html-form-to-a-python-script-in-flask

Answer (score 1):

Wrap button with form:

```html
<form action="/submit_a" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="A" value="submit_A">
</form>
```

Comment: Your closing tag is wrong - you need to replace the question mark with a slash.

Comment: Yes, typo in closing tag