# How to get test input from an html form to another python script using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to get a simple web form up and running that only asks for a URL.

This is the HTML Code (index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form name = 'test' action = "." method = "post">
            <form action="test.php" method="get">
                URL <input type="text" link="link" name = "URL"/>
                <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using Flask to run the simple web application this is the Flask Code: (app.py)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/", methods = ["POST"])

def get_value():
    url = request.form["URL"]
    return 'The url is ' + url

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and I'm trying to get the inputted URL to another python script so I can do something with it, this is the other python script: (url.py)

```
from app import get_value

print(get_value())
```

However, whenever I run python3 url.py it gives me this error:

```
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

Any idea how to print get the URL over successfully? In a lot of detail preferably because I am very new to Flask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you called a function that needs data from a request to get the user inputs. You should call the url handling function instead letting the handling function call the retrieval of the url.

Consider this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566296/5368402 to make sure you pass the url correctly. Now that you have your url, simply pass it to your other script.

```
import url # your url.py module

@app.route("/", methods = ["POST"])

def get_value():
    input_url = request.form["URL"]
    url.handle_url(input_url) #call a function inside url.py
```