# Cannot POST simple HTML form with Flask (Python)

Tags: python, html, flask

This is an incredibly simple question and I am ashamed to be asking it here, but I have been Googling answers for the past 3 hours with no results.

Basically, I am trying to send information using an HTML form and accept that information with a Flask python script. The problem is whenever I try to submit the form, it says Cannot POST path/form.html

The HTML Form:

```
<form method="post"> 
<label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="fname" placeholder="firstname">
<label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lname" placeholder="lastname">
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

The Python/Flask Code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template  

# Flask constructor
app = Flask(__name__)

# A decorator used to tell the application
# which URL is associated function
@app.route('/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def gfg():
    if request.method == "POST":
       # getting input with name = fname in HTML form
       first_name = request.form.get("fname")
       # getting input with name = lname in HTML form
       last_name = request.form.get("lname")
       return "Your name is "+first_name + last_name
    return render_template("form.html")

if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run()
```

I know this should be simple but web development is not my forte and this is really out of my element. Is this a server problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11556958/sending-data-from-html-form-to-a-python-script-in-flask

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately it does not

Comment: @RichardMcCormick it does, go read it again. You don't have an action path set, and it's trying to POST to the page it came from.

Comment: Where do I set the action path to? I have tried using the folder which contains both files but this is not working either.

Comment: To whatever the URL of your Flask app is.  Looks like "path/" maybe?

Comment: I think this may work for you `<form action="{{ url_for('gfg') }}" method="post">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
@app.route('/', methods =["GET", "POST"])
def gfg():
    if request.method == "POST":
       # getting input with name = fname in HTML form
       if "fname" in request.form:
           first_name = request.form['fname]
       # getting input with name = lname in HTML form
       if "lname" in request.form:
           last_name = request.form["lname"]
    
       if first_name and last_name:
           print("Your name is "+first_name + last_name)
           
    return render_template("form.html")
```

Comment: Did this answer help you?