# Passing value from HTML to Python function

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to HTML so having a bit of an issue with passing a value from HTML to python function. So what I am doing is making buttons with a loop, code is following:

**Python Code for making buttons:**

```
@app.route('/Ongoing', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def Ongoing():
id = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
length = 8
return render_template('Run.html', length=length, id=id)
```

**Html code for Buttons:**

```
{% for i in range(length) %}
<form id="btn" action="{{ url_for('detail') }}" method="GET">
    <button type="submit" class="submit-btn-choice" style="margin-top: 20px;">Name</button>
</form>
{%endfor%}
```

Now I have 8 buttons. So what I want is when I press the first button first value of **id** which is **1** should be sent back to the called function(**detail**). In the same way when the second button is pressed value of 2 is sent back with it.

The function to which value is send is following:

```
@app.route('/detail', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def detail(id):
response = Coup_data(id)
return render_template('detail.html', response =response )
```

I would really appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have managed to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566296/16540015) response to a similar question. Basically, your form (when submitted) will send it's value (with a  `multipart/form-data` MIME type), and then you can read the values in  your API method.

That being said, your HTML `<form>` doesn't have any fields or `<input>` elements in it - so it's just going to send empty data to the backend on submission. It'll take some reworking, but you could update your API route to accept URL parameters, and then in your template, specify the `id`:

`<form id="btn" action="{{ url_for('detail', id=id) }}" method="GET">`

Your API URL would look like `/detail?id=1`

And then for your route, parse `request.args` ([docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.Request.args)) for the `id`

Comment: Thanks for reply, Although I have managed to solve the issue but I will try it for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem though don't know how efficient or bad the logic is. The changes that I have made are following:

**Html code for Buttons:**

Here I have used **name** and **value** property to identify pressed button and changed method to **POST**

```
{% for i in range(length) %}
<form id="btn" action="{{ url_for('detail') }}" method="POST">
   <button type="submit" class="submit-btn-choice" style="margin-top: 20px;" name="Val" value="{{id[i]}}">Name</button>
</form>
{%endfor%}
```

**Called Function Code:**

Here I am receiving posted value using **request.form** and use it for my function call.

```
@app.route('/detail', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def detail():
if request.method == 'POST':
    id = request.form.get('Val')
response = Coup_data(id)
return render_template('detail.html', response =response )
```