# Flask, run python function from html without opneing new url

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning flask and I'm building a project with ebay api.

Python:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, request
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection

app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return render_template('search_on_ebay.html')
    
    def get_data():    
        api = Connection(config_file='ebay.yml', siteid="EBAY-US")
        request_ = {
            'keywords': 'vasco rossi',
            'itemFilter': [
                {'name': 'condition', 'value': 'new'}
            ],
            'paginationInput': {
                'entriesPerPage': 10,
                'pageNumber': 1
            },
            'sortOrder': 'PricePlusShippingLowest'
        }
        response = api.execute('findItemsByKeywords', request_)
        array_data = []
        for item in response.reply.searchResult.item:
            print(f"Title: {item.title}, Price: {item.sellingStatus.currentPrice.value}")
            array_data.append(item.title)
            array_data.append(item.sellingStatus.currentPrice.value)
        return f'{array_data}'
```

in html I have two forms with input and button:

```
<div id="search-div" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
     <form>
            <input type="text" name="searchinput" style="margin-top: -20px; margin-left: 2px; width: 20%;" id="search-input">
            </form>
            <label style="color:#eeeeee">a</label>
            <form action="**HERE I WANT TO RUN THE FUNCTION**" method="POST">
                <button text="cerca" id="search-button" class="button-primary">search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

I wanted to run first function, named index, at the begin of the site (that works) and get_data when I click the search button.
I can't do it opening another url, because my site needs to get keywords from the input, and if I open a new url the input disappers.
How can I do?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at these [Flask docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/fileuploads/)?

if someone makes a `get` request, you can render your HTML form, and if someone makes a `post` request (via your form), you can run your function.

you can surround your function with:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

(do stuff here)
return
```

also don't forget to set the methods for your route (I believe routes only accept `get` by default) like this:

`@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566296/19373112) has some relevant info as well.

Comment: but if i change the url, it returns element of that url, not of my previous page..

Comment: you don't need to change the URL. did you read the answer I linked to above?